# Invalidate the query with React Query 4 in a Context Provider gives unexpected result

Tags: reactjs, tanstackreact-query

In a React Project there is a Context Provider called "StaticDataProvider".

With this the UI project gets the static data from the API and puts it in the Context for use in Components.

The StaticDataProvider looks like this:

```js
import {
    createContext,
    ReactNode,
    useContext,
    useState,
    useEffect,
} from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { useToken } from '../../../lib';
import { GetAllReferenceData } from '../../../requests';
import { StaticDataInterface, initialStaticData } from './initialStaticData';

export const StaticDataContext =
    createContext<StaticDataInterface>(initialStaticData);

export const useStaticData = () => useContext(StaticDataContext);

export function StaticDataProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
    // ** Init the State with initial Static Data.
    const [refData, setRefData] =
        useState<StaticDataInterface>(initialStaticData);

    const token = useToken(); // Needed for the Query to the API

    // ** Fetch Reference Data
    const {
        data: referenceData,
        isSuccess,
        isLoading,
    } = useQuery('reference_data', () => GetAllReferenceData(token));

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isSuccess) {
            setRefData({
                ...initialStaticData,
                referenceData,
            });
        } 
    }, [isLoading, isSuccess]);

    if (isLoading && !isSuccess) {
        return null; // Forget about showing anything if we don't have StaticData.
    }
    return (
        <StaticDataContext.Provider value={refData}>
            {children}
        </StaticDataContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

When the application loads, StaticData is available, but only the init version since you're not logged in (and therefore don't have accessToken to go to the API).

Upon Login the 'reference_data' key is invalidated and the data is loaded from the API.
All works as expected.

The problem is that sometimes in the Application something happens which requires a reload of StaticData. (You could say that my Static Data is not really "Static" :-) )
Then a new 'invalidateQueries' command on key "reference_data" is sent.
This invalidation works ok (I see the request coming in on the API side).

But the problem is that the useEffect in the StaticData Provider is not executed, and thereby the setRefData (to the State) is not executed.
The dependency of the useEffect is both 'isLoading' and 'isSuccess'. They will change during the running of the query. Then why is the useEffect not executed?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Think I solved this:

1. Adding the 'referenceData' to the dependencies array of the useEffect.
2. HotReloading code does mess up the caching mechanism of React-Query. So, if you hot-reload your code, it doesn't work anymore.

Especially the last one can really put you off track in figuring out what's going on here. ...